# Why does $\bigcup_{i\in\emptyset}i=\emptyset$ (the empty union)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, trees, convention

It seems that the consensus/convention is that the empty union, $\bigcup_{i\in\emptyset}i=\emptyset$

At first glance this seems intuitive, however please consider my following arguments and let me know where I go wrong.

Let $a_0=\emptyset$, $a_{n+1}=\{a_n\}$. (e.g; $a_3=\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$)

$$a_{n}\neq a_m \iff m \neq n$$

For ease of notation, let $f(S)=\bigcup_{i\in S}i$

$$\therefore f(a_{n+1})=\bigcup_{i\in a_{n+1}}i=\bigcup_{i\in \{a_n\}}i=a_n$$
$$\implies f(a_0)=a_{-1}=f(\emptyset)=\bigcup_{i\in \emptyset}i=\emptyset$$
$$\implies a_0=a_{-1}$$

Why should it be the case that the equivalence of $a_{n}\neq a_m \iff m \neq n$ fails when $m=0$ and $n=-1$? Would it not be more intuitive to define $a_{-1}$ as undefined, rather than accepting the convention?

If $f(\emptyset)$ describes the union of the elements of $\emptyset$, the set than contains *nothing*; which (at least) linguistically is equivalent to the union of *nothing*. I notice that the set containing *nothing* is distinct from *nothing* itself. Thus, why is the convention nondistinct? Would it not be more intuitive to instead define $\emptyset \neq f(\emptyset)$.

Lastly, consider how there is a one-to-one correspondence between finitary pure sets and rooted identity trees (see [A004111](https://oeis.org/A004111) on the OEIS). The previous series of $a_n$ would correspond to a unique tree of $n+1$ nodes. Hence, $a_{-1}$ corresponds to a tree of $0$ nodes, which is equivalent to no set at all, strictly distinct from the empty set.

Comment: If you want $$\bigcup_{i \in S}\,i=\bigcup_{i\in S\cup \emptyset} \,i=\left(\bigcup_{i\in S}\,i\right)\cup\left(\bigcup_{i\in \emptyset}\,i\right)$$ for all sets $S$, then you need to define $$\bigcup_{i\in \emptyset}\,i:=\emptyset\,.$$  Likewise, If you want $$\bigcap_{i \in S}\,i=\bigcap_{i\in S\cup \emptyset} \,i=\left(\bigcap_{i\in S}\,i\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{i\in \emptyset}\,i\right)$$ for all sets $S$, then you need to define $$\bigcap_{i\in \emptyset}\,i:=\mathcal{U}\,,$$ where $\mathcal{U}$ is the universe.

Comment: @Batominovski Ahah, this is a very strong argument indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set. The axiom of union (in [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)) states that
$$\{u:(\exists v)[u\in v\in X]\}=: \bigcup X$$
is a set.

Now let $X$ be the empty set $\varnothing$. Then
$$\bigcup \varnothing=\{u:(\exists v)[u\in v\in\varnothing]\}=\varnothing.$$
Indeed, the first equality is simply a definition and the second equality follows because there does not exist an element in $\{u:(\exists v)[u\in v\in\varnothing]\}$.