# Different definitions for topology induced by a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

So usually, the topology induced by a metric $d$ is defined as the topology that is generated by the open balls (where the open balls are defined with respect to that metric $d$).

Now I have come across the following definition for the topology induced by a metric:
$$\tau_d = \{\emptyset\}\cup\{U\subseteq X: U \text{ is the union of open balls in } X\} $$

So my question is: Why does the author include the empty set here? Isnt the set $\{U\subseteq X: U \text{ is the union of open balls in } X\}$ already equivalent to the standard definition of the topology induced by a metric?

Comment: It is, as long as you allow open balls with radius $0$, which are empty, or an empty union.

Comment: Do you mean "is the union of *some* open balls in $X$"? Besides, I agree with Captain Lama. Who is this "author"?

Comment: @AnneBauval no, i have copied the definition 1:1 as i have encountered it in the lecture notes i found

Comment: @CaptainLama but the open balls are defined with strictly positive radius here...

Comment: Were these lecture note in english or did you translate for us? Who is the "author"? + if they forbid $r=0,$ an [empty union](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626572) will do.

Comment: Well then it depends if you allow an empty union. But you know, sometimes an author might add something which is not technically necessary if they think it improves clarity. So if the author thought that some readers might forget that the empty union is allowed, they could add the empty set to make sure that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: what is meant by empty union? Does it have to be stated somewhere whether it is used or is it convention?

Comment: Just to make a point, using that an "open ball" is defined with strictly positive radius, it follows that the set $\{U \subseteq X : U$ is the union of a *nonempty* collection of open balls in $X \}$ certainly does not have the empty set as one of its elements, so it is not a topology, and in particular it is not the topology generated by the metric.

Comment: @LeeMosher But the "author" did not add this "*nonempty*", so (since they do not forbid the empty collection) their $\{\varnothing\}$ is redundant. @ guest1: there is a link to "empty union" in my previous comment.

Comment: @LeeMosher so is the set that you have written down the case where the "empty union" is excluded? And would your set together with the empty set be a topology?

Comment: @guest1 Yes, that is correct. But as suggested by Captain Lama, in applications of set theory (such as its application to topology) the default understanding sometimes does allow empty unions.